# ClassNotFoundException error and reflection

Tags: java, variables, reflection, classnotfoundexception

I am able to access a class and its variables, but is there anyway in changing a user defined variable?

e.g:

```
Class c = Class.forName(theclassname);
    Object o = c.newInstance();
    theclassname t = (theclassname) o;
```

i can do

```
t.variable = 1;
```

but can i do

```
String v = "variable";
t.v = 1;
```

in any way?

Comment: `C:\\A.txt` is a file name not a class name...

Comment: C:\A.txt is a text file ... a class file should end with `.class` !

Comment: ow yeah. wops :3 any idea's on the second?

Comment: Well you can't do it like that - you need to use reflection, via `Class.getField` and `Field.put` etc.

Comment: The question has totally changed from the one before the edit ...

Comment: *"any idea's on the second?"*  Please ask one specific question per ..question.  This is a Q&A site, not a help desk!

Comment: @Andrew Thompsonit is one question sorry i was talking about before I edited it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't use

```
Class c = Class.forName("C:\\A.txt");
```

on that way.

This piece of code returns Class by provided name, not the txt file.

Instead of this situation, you have to create class (suppose that is a class named A) and then retrieve Class `A` over reflection with following code:

```
Class c = Class.forName("A");
```

Note that is a class, not a txt file.

---EDIT---

**With this edit you are completely changed the question.**
Based on the new (edited) question, you can't use reflection as you wrote:

```
t.v = 1;
```

You should use this code:

```
t.getClass().getField(v).set(t, 1);
```

That will solve your problem.

Answer (score 1):

`C:\A.txt` is a text file ... a class file should end with `.class` !

Write a class `A.java` then compile it using

```
javac A.java
```

then you'll get `A.class` then you can load it using

```
Class c = Class.forName("A");
```

Note here that `"A"` is not the absolute or relative path to some file on the filesystem but the name of the resource for that class on the classpath. See the javadoc for [Class#forName](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html#forName%28java.lang.String%29)

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/eUUjF.png still doesnt work while using `Class c = Class.forName("A");` or `Class c = Class.forName("C:\\A.class");`

Comment: @user2871826 You have to have `A.class` in your class path.

Comment: @user2871826 forget about `Class.forName("C:\\A.class");` it will never ever work! What is the package of your class, `Class.forName("A")` assumes that is in the default package.

Comment: It is an example so i dont have to write the whole path down, but never the less using the class path to access a .class file which is next to the other .class it is being accessed from it doesn't work.

Comment: @A4l it is in the package "Mk01.Server.src.carcass.test" and the class file is called "AExampleTestClass.class" no matter what i put in .forname. it doesnt work.

Comment: @user2871826 I assume that `Mk01\Server\src` is just the directory where all your sources are. Use `Class.forName("carcass.test.AExampleTestClass")`, if this does not work then the class you are trying to load is not on the class path of the application you are trying to it from. In that case use the `-cp` option to expand the classpath.

Comment: "Mk01.Server.src.carcass.test.AExampleTestClass" got it to work sorry for being a nuisance.

Comment: @user2871826 cool, but `Mk01.Server.src` is rather unusual and misleading as package name.

Comment: @A4L yeah I'm no good at naming, especially with this application, its hard to manage 118 classes which are in 45 folders.I had .src. as it was part of another app which i put into it cause the whole thing is 2 separate applications in one folder. (client and server). I guess I could always re-factor them.

Answer (score 1):

You can use reflections to set a field like this

```
String v = "variable";
// like t.{v} = 1;
t.getClass().getField(v).set(t, 1);
```